# Gradle duplicate dependency?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I've been using Gradle for some time now. I'm having the following problem with dependencies: let's say the main project, "A" depends on "B", "B" depends on "X", but "A" also depends on "X". Will my project have a duplicate dependency of "X"?

Also, should release JARs include dependencies?

I'm using https://jitpack.io/ to import my own projects.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate dependency"? What do you think is a duplicate dependency, and why should that be a bad thing?